# boost::udp socket.recieve_from() appends data to the end of the buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I have implemented a udp_client using `boost_asio`  The udp_client::recieve_from() is given below.

```
void udp_client::recieve_from()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_buffer_manager.get_recieve_array().size(); ++i)
        m_buffer_manager.get_recieve_array()[i] = 0;

    /*Initialize our endpoint*/
    size_t len = m_socket.receive_from(
                     boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer_manager.get_recieve_array()), m_sender_endpoint);

    m_buffer_manager.message_buffer(m_buffer_manager.get_recieve_array(),len);
    std::cout << "Length of recieved message " << len << std::endl;
    /*dumps the message into std::cout for debugging.*/
    std::cout << m_buffer_manager.get_message_string() << std::endl;
    //std::cout.write((const char*)&m_buffer_manager.get_recieve_array()[0], len);

    packet_t ack_packet = { "ACK", {} };
    auto buffer = ack_packet.serialize();
    m_socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), m_endpoint);
}
```

The `udp_client.hpp` file is shown below.

```
class udp_client
{
public:
    udp_client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,const std::string& host,const std::string& port);
    ~udp_client();
    void subscribe();
    void publish(const std::string& message);
    void recieve_from();

private:
    boost::asio::io_service& m_io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::socket m_socket;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::endpoint m_endpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_sender_endpoint;
    buffer_manager m_buffer_manager;
};
```

The `buffer_manager` object that is used to manage the recieve buffer is shown below.

```
class buffer_manager
{
public:
    typedef boost::array<unsigned char, 4096> m_array_type;
    buffer_manager();
    ~buffer_manager();
    void message_buffer(m_array_type &recv_buf,size_t size);
    buffer_manager::m_array_type & get_recieve_array();
    std::string & get_message_string();

private:
    std::string m_message;
    m_array_type m_recv_buf;
};
```

My problem with the udp_client::recieve_from() code is that

`size_t len = m_socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer_manager.get_recieve_array()), m_sender_endpoint);`

returns 1 packet after recieving one packet. When it recieves two packets it recieves the entire two packets. (i.e the contents of the second packet are appended to the contents of the first packet.)

This is inspite of

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_buffer_manager.get_recieve_array().size(); ++i)
            m_buffer_manager.get_recieve_array()[i] = 0;
```

where I explictly clear the buffer. What is the reason for this? How do I get around this issue.?

Please find the implementation for buffer_manager.cpp below.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include "buffer_manager.hpp"

buffer_manager::buffer_manager()
{

}
buffer_manager::~buffer_manager()
{

}
void buffer_manager::message_buffer(m_array_type &recv_buf,size_t size)
{
    auto it = recv_buf.begin();
    std::advance(it,size);
    boost::algorithm::hex(recv_buf.begin(), it, back_inserter(m_message));
}

buffer_manager::m_array_type& buffer_manager::get_recieve_array()
{
    return m_recv_buf;
}

std::string & buffer_manager::get_message_string()
{
    return m_message;
}
```

Comment: I suggest the problem is not with boost::asio but with the management of the string in the buffer manager. Hard to see the actual point of this class.

Comment: @EJP - I have two client, server implementations. (TCP and UDP).Both TCP and UDP client uses buffer_manager to manage the buffer.It was created for data abstraction. I am a beginner in C++. does this make sense?

Comment: I don't know. Show us the implementation. It doesn't appear to do anything useful that a char array doesn't already provide.

Comment: If a single UDP read operation populates the read buffer with unexpected duplicate data, then it is very likely that the sender is sending the duplicated data.  Consider verifying that the sender is populating the buffer properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `receive_from()` operation is functioning properly and not appending data to the end of the buffer.  On the other hand, `buffer_manager::message_buffer()` is appending to `m_message` on each invocation, as it uses a `back_insert_iterator` and never clears the string.

```cpp
void buffer_manager::message_buffer(...)
{
  auto it = recv_buf.begin();
  std::advance(it, size);
  boost::algorithm::hex(recv_buf.begin(), it, back_inserter(m_message));
                                           // ^~~ invokes m_message.push_back() for the
                                           //     range [recv_buf.begin(), it).
}
```

To resolve this, consider clearing the string beforehand.

```
void buffer_manager::message_buffer(...)
{
  auto it = recv_buf.begin();
  std::advance(it, size);
  m_message.clear();
  boost::algorithm::hex(recv_buf.begin(), it, back_inserter(m_message));
```

---

Here is a minimal example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6d48841a00f2074) `std::back_inserter`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string message = "abc";
  auto inserter = back_inserter(message);
  inserter = 'd';
  inserter = 'e';
  assert("abcde" == message);
}
```

---

It is not clear to me what value the `buffer_manager` provides.  However, if you want to print the hex-value of a buffer, consider writing to the `ostream` using an `ostream_iterator` without the overhead of constructing a `string`.  For example, the following utility function writes the hex values of an iterator range to the provided `ostream`:

```cpp
template <typename Iterator>
void write_hex(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::ostream& out)
{
  boost::algorithm::hex(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<char>(out));
}
```

and its usage:

```cpp
unsigned char data[3] = { 0, 10, 255 };
write_hex(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::cout); // writes 000AFF to stdout.
```

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6fabe7ef2d793d2) printing the hex-value of various buffer types to stdout using the `write_hex` function and with a custom type to streamline writing hex to an `ostream`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>

// Utility funciton to write hex to a stream.
template <typename Iterator>
void write_hex(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::ostream& out)
{
  boost::algorithm::hex(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<char>(out));
}

namespace detail {

// Utility type to write an iterable as hex to a stream via the insertion
// operator.
template <typename Iterable>
struct hex_writer
{
  const Iterable& iterable;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const hex_writer& object)
  {
    write_hex(std::begin(object.iterable), std::end(object.iterable), stream);
    return stream;
  }  
};

} // namespace detail

// Auxiliary function to create hex_writers.  Intended to be used for
// chaining writes to an ostream.
template <typename Iterable>
detail::hex_writer<Iterable> as_hex(const Iterable& iterable)
{
  return {iterable};
}

int main()
{
  // Using c-array.
  {
    unsigned char data[3] = { 0, 10, 255 };
    write_hex(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::cout);
    std::cout << " " << as_hex(data) << std::endl;
  }

  // Using c++-array.
  {
    std::array<unsigned char, 3> data = {{ 0, 10, 255 }};
    write_hex(begin(data), end(data), std::cout);
    std::cout << " " << as_hex(data) << std::endl;
  }

  // Using vector.
  {
    std::vector<unsigned char> data = { 0, 10, 255 };
    write_hex(begin(data), end(data), std::cout);
    std::cout << " " << as_hex(data) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
000AFF 000AFF
000AFF 000AFF
000AFF 000AFF
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're clearing the buffer beforehand provides conclusively that the problem isn't in boost::asio, unless you're suggesting that it keeps a memory for some unknown purpose.

Either:

1. The sender is sending datagrams with duplicated data, or
2. The problem lies somewhere in your buffer manager class, probably the string thing.

   I don't see the point of this class. I suggest you rewrite the code using a char array like everybody else.

Comment: Please tell us which it was, and/or delete your question.